# Postgres: How to disable logging long calls of stored procedures?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, logging

A lot of logic in my application resides inside stored plpgsql procedures. As a result a single call can take seconds or even minutes to complete. This is perfectly fine, but I want to use `log_min_duration_statement = 250ms` for all other statements to track long queries. Is it possible to configure Postgres so that long stored procedure calls are not logged at all?

I came up with manually disabling logging for each session that calls stored procedures with

```
SELECT set_config('log_min_duration_statement', '-1', false)
```

Unfortunately, this means that my application would require a superuser role and I would like to avoid it.

Comment: it is unavoidable. if not superuser could change this setting they could run long "hacking" queries and superuser would not notice it in logs. Instead maybe you want to trry `pg_stat_statements` extension?.. much easier to browse it by querying...

Comment: I meant so you can `select * from pg_stat_statements where query != 'WANTED TO BE AVOIDED'`

Comment: Good idea! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Superuser rights are unavoidable for `set`ting this parameters.

if not superuser could change this setting they could run long "hacking" queries and superuser would not notice it in logs. Instead maybe you want to trry `pg_stat_statements` extension?.. much easier to browse it by querying...

you can `select * from pg_stat_statements where query != 'WANTED TO BE AVOIDED'`